# SObject isSet function

Tags: apex

This is a question about the [`isSet`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_isSet) function on SObjects.

Even though the documentation says it has a void type, it really is a boolean.

The sample in documentation provided is quite simple and works fine:

```
Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Joyce');
System.assertEquals(true, c.isSet('LastName'));
System.assertEquals(true, c.isSet(Contact.LastName));
```

However the `isSet` function doesn't seem to work for `OwnerId` only when using the `Schema.SObjectField` parameter version

```
Contact c = new Contact(OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId());
System.assertEquals(true, c.isSet('OwnerId')); // works fine
System.assertEquals(true, c.isSet(Contact.OwnerId)); // Fails
```

I've tried `isSet` with other polymorphic lookup fields like `Task.WhatId` and this behaviour appears to be the same for those as well.

Is this expected? what am I missing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is expected behavior, because when sObject is not created yet, the lookup fields will not appear as you expect in the isSet method with parameter of SObjectField Class.

However, after insertion there is possibility to retrieve OwnerId.

```
Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Joyce', OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId());
insert c;
c = [SELECT LastName, Owner.Id FROM Contact LIMIT 1];
System.assertEquals(true, c.isSet('OwnerId')); // works fine
System.assertEquals(true, c.isSet(Contact.OwnerId)); // works fine
```

**Note:**

If you make select like this: `c = [SELECT LastName, OwnerId FROM Contact LIMIT 1];` (**OwnerId** instead of **Owner.Id**) it will fail:

```
Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Joyce', OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId());
insert c;
c = [SELECT LastName, OwnerId FROM Contact LIMIT 1];
System.assertEquals(true, c.isSet('OwnerId')); // works fine
System.assertEquals(true, c.isSet(Contact.OwnerId)); // fails
```

**Note 2:**

However, it will work like this:

```
Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Joyce', OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId());
insert c;
c = [SELECT LastName, OwnerId FROM Contact LIMIT 1];
System.assertEquals(true, c.isSet('OwnerId')); // works fine
System.assertEquals(true, c.isSet(Contact.Owner.Id)); // works fine
```

**P.S.:** that bothers me too, but this is how it works.